# CGContext 'addPath' to the existing drawing

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, cgcontext

I have a CGPath drawn in a custom UIView as follows. There is a refresh button that is supposed to add new line to the path already drawn.

```
 private func refresh() {
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect){
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        return
    }
    
    context.setLineWidth(1)
    context.addPath(self.newPathPart())
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    context.interpolationQuality = .none
    context.setAllowsAntialiasing(false)
    context.setShouldAntialias(false)
    context.strokePath()
   
}

private func newPathPart() -> CGPath {
   let lineWidth: CGFloat = 1
    
    let mPath        = CGMutablePath()
    
    if lastPoint == nil {
        lastPoint = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX - lineWidth/2, y: self.bounds.midY - lineWidth/2)
    }
    
    mPath.move(to: lastPoint!)
   
    mPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: lastPoint!.x + 15, y: lastPoint!.y + 15))

    lastPoint = CGPoint(x: lastPoint!.x + 15, y: lastPoint!.y + 15)
    mPath.closeSubpath()
   
    return mPath
}
```

I had an impression that the newPartPath() will be appended to existing path that is drawn but that seems not to be the case. I wish to optimise the code so that I do not completely redraw the whole path on every refresh, but just the path that is added. How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep on hand a CGMutablePath, or a collection of CGPaths, so that you can keep accumulating new path parts in an actual CGPath.

When `draw` is called, it has a `rect`. You are ignoring that parameter. Don't ignore it. You only need to supply the part of the drawing that is in that `rect`. So examine the `rect` and draw in such a way as to supply the missing part of the drawing that does into it. In other words, you draw just the parts of your path that intersect that `rect`.

Note that if *you* are the one responsible for knowing that there is a new part of the path waiting to be drawn, you can call `setNeedsDisplay(in:)` with the `rect` of that part of the path, so that that is the `rect` that is asked for in `draw`.

Comment: It works by computing a *subPath* and appending it to *existingPath*. Then use *rect = subPath.boundingBox* in *setNeedsDisplay(in:rect.insetBy(dx:-2, dy:-2))*. Without adding inset to the boundingBox there are drawing artifacts at the end points of subPath.

Comment: For some reason, the rect I pass in setNeedsDisplay(in:) is not honoured, the whole view is redrawn and the rect parameter in draw(in:rect) is view.bounds. Any idea how it can happen?

Comment: I think setNeedsDisplay(in:rect) is not honoring the rect parameter making the call useless. Are you aware of this issue in iOS?